# Send data from one page to another instead of preloading?

Tags: svelte, sapper, svelte-3

Say I have a `blog` route that loads a complete array of all blog posts. The individual blog posts live at `blog/[postId]`. Is there a Sapper-idiomatic way to pass the data for the individual post from `blog` to `blog/[postId]`?

Essentially, if you're on `blog` I'd like to preload the code for displaying `blog/[postId]`. And then when you click a link to `blog/[postId]`, navigate there instantly and display data from `blog`. But of course if you navigate directly to `blog/[postId]` then `preload()` should still be called.

`prefetch` doesn't quite do it because that still requires a network request. I also tried a preload that checks a store and doesn't issue the network request unless its empty, but you can't use stores in `<script context="module">`.

Comment: You could probably do that in your layout route. If that lives in your blog directory you can preload all posts in there and then according to each id you display that data. But I would probably just preload a single blog id and then once it's loaded fetch all the other posts and store them in a store.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It set me on the path to figuring it out. Turns out `preload()` always gets called on navigation, regardless of whether its in `_layout.svelte`, a regular page component, or both. I ended up storing the data in the second parameter to `preload()`, `session`, and only calling `this.fetch()` if it was empty or stale.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @three for [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201324/send-data-from-one-page-to-another-instead-of-preloading?noredirect=1#comment106484087_60201324) which led me to the answer.

If a route or `_layout` component exports `preload()`, it always gets called on navigation. So I ended up doing this by storing the fetched data in the second parameter to `preload()`, which is conventionally called `session` and appears to be shared among all components. And I only called `this.fetch()` if the data was not already present.

```html
<!-- blog/index.svelte -->
<script context="module">
  export async function preload (page, session) {
    let {posts} = session;
    if (undefined === posts) {
      const response = await this.fetch('blog/posts.json');
      posts = await response.json();
      session.posts = posts
    }

    return {posts}
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let posts;
</script>

{#each posts as post}
  <!-- ... -->
{/each}
```

Then in `[slug].svelte` check `session.posts` for the post you're looking for, and if it isn't present, load it.

```html
<!-- blog/[slug].svelte -->
<script context="module">
  export async function preload (page, session) {
    const {slug} = page.params
    const {posts} = session
    let post

    if (undefined === posts) {
      const response = await this.fetch(`blog/${slug}.json`)
      post = await response.json()
    } else {
      post = posts.find(p => p.slug === slug)
    }

    if (undefined === post) {
      this.error(404, "Sorry we couldn\'t find that post")
    }

    return {post}
  }
</script>

<script>
  export let post
</script>

<!-- ... render post -->
```

Now navigation is instantaneous. For ultimate robustness you could add checks to reload if the data were stale (say older than 5 minutes, whatever).

#### Edit

You don't actually need to be using sessions, per se. If you just want to make the `session` parameter to `preload(page, session)` not be `undefined` you can use this in `server.js`:

```js
sapper.middleware({
  // Define session parameter as an empty object
  session: (req, res) => ({})
})
```